# postgres functions loses column names

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I create a function in the PgAdmin query tool that returns a table with a single column:

```
create or replace function test_function()
  returns table(a integer) as
...
```

When I run the query, I get a success message and can see the function added to the list, but the definition is stored as:

```
create or replace function test_function()
  returns setof integer as
...
```

This only seems to happen for single column returns. It is causing me problems because if I want to create a statement like:

```
select t.a from test_function();
```

I cannot, the column name takes on strange name and I get an error message that the return type has no column a. How can I force this to return a table?

Comment: Strange, this may be some pgAdmin bug ... for a workaround, you can indicate output column names with named `OUT` parameter(s) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/82074/4

Comment: @pozs thanks that does the trick. I found a bug report here http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200904161248.n3GCmI9c027460@wwwmaster.postgresql.org
 but it was from a long time ago, and updating to the latest version doesn't help.

Comment: Does `pg_get_function_def()` also return the wrong information?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, it that ouput still shows the function returning a `setof` rather than a `table`.

Comment: Then this is rather a Postgres problem, not a pgAdmin problem. Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using 8.4.20

Comment: I can't reproduce this with 9.1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/61368/1 9.2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/61368/1 or 9.3: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/613684/1 or 9.4. Maybe this is caused by your outdated Postgres version.

Comment: I had a similar problem long time ago. I used something like: select a from test_function() AS a;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in pgAdmin (reported [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAANrE7rZGs58emrPK9xEaCz2kDBr33v8dNvQ_14KXuJp7v9B3A@mail.gmail.com)).

The function definition is stored correctly when you first create it. pgAdmin displays it incorrectly, but calls to the function should still behave as expected.

The problem only arises when you take pgAdmin's `CREATE OR REPLACE` statement and run it. The recreation will appear to succeed, but the function will fail at runtime due to the missing variable declaration.

As long as you remember to fix the return type every time you recreate the function, you shouldn't have a problem.